# State is not properly updated with useRef to update only if there is a change

Tags: reactjs

I am using useRef and useState to keep track of values that I am receiving all the time through socket.io, I also have an if check that checks if there is any difference between the objects and if there is, only then assign the new values, to avoid useless state updates. However, for some reason, useRef doesnt keep the copy of the old variable and is just empty, and gives me the undefined errors:

```
  const [robots, setRobots] = useState(robotsConfig);
  const prevRobots = useRef(robotsConfig);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    prevRobots.current = robots;
  }, [robots]);

  socket.on(event, (data) => {
    if (!(JSON.stringify(prevRobots.current[robotName].Data) === JSON.stringify(data)) {

      // this gives me an empty object {}
      console.log(JSON.stringify(prevRobots.current[robotName].Data)); 

      setRobots((prevState) => (
        { 
          ...prevState, 
          [robotName]: { 
            ...prevState[robotName], 
            Data: data 
        }
      );

      console.log("Data updated");
    }
  });
```

The if statement is always executed and prevRobots.current is empty. I've tried setting it to an empty object initially "{}", or to robotsConfig, just like robots, at least then it doesnt break, but neither helped and the code within the if keeps getting executed everytime I receive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form of `useState` and return the same value if nothing should change. From the docs: *"If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely."*
- You also likely want to wrap that `socket.on` in a `useEffect` so it's executed only once

```js
const [robots, setRobots] = useState(robotsConfig);

useEffect(() => {
  function messageHandler(data) {
    setRobots((prevRobots) => {
      if (!(JSON.stringify(prevRobots.Data) === JSON.stringify(data)) {
        return { 
          ...prevRobots, 
          [robotName]: { 
            ...prevRobots[robotName], 
            Data: data 
          }
        };
        console.log("Data updated");
      } else {
        return prevRobots;
      }
    });
  }

  socket.on(event, messageHandler);
  return () => {
    socket.off(event, messageHandler)
  }
}, [event, socket]);
```

Comment: I cant wrap the socket in an useEffect, because I am constantly receiving data, that is why I need to manually check if data has changed and only then trigger a state change, otherwise it becomes a complete mess and state change gets initiated all the time. I have tried putting the if check within the setRobots like you did, but it is still getting triggered everytime an event occurs, even tho the data is the same.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(prevRobots.current[robotName].PRData)); if I add this inside the if it gives me an empty object {}, PRData initially is indeed {}, but why it doesnt get updated, once it gets inside the if and updates robots... the useEffect should take care of that since robots is being changed

Comment: "I cant wrap the socket in an useEffect, because I am constantly receiving data" -- if you don't wrap it in a `useEffect` then this will add a new listener to the socket every time the component renders; it'll end up with a bunch of listeners on the socket.

Comment: Ohhh!!!! You are right! Sorry! So what I was seeing was actually a new socket listener being initiated everytime I receive data thats why it was always giving me {} for the ref robots, cuz for every new listener its empty. It is working now! :)

Comment: Great! Glad it's all working. I guessed on the `socket.off` function call, but that should unsubscribe in case the socket changes or the name of the event changes.

Comment: Yeah, ill probabky add socket offs and make it dependable on what is the user currently viewing so that im not monitoring all possibke events all the time, but its good enough for now